# Azure Pipeline dotnet push error finding nuget package

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package, azure-pipelines-yaml

My code for the azure pipeline
[image]

I have Problems using the azure pipeline, which will automatically pack my libraries on azure devops git and push it as a nugetpackage to artifacts.

I get the error **##[error]No packages matched the search pattern.**
at dotnet push

Until that step everything works. I want to pack it as a nuget so i can use it in other projects.
Its a API Client i wrote for my own API.

Comment: why dont you use azure artifacts?

Comment: thats what i try to do. I coded a net5.0 api client lib for my web api i have. and i wanna package and push it to artifacts, so i can use it in my other applications. Is my approach  wrong with this pipeline? It should automatically generate a new nuget pkg whenever i change my api client lib.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the artifact path from artifact staging directory

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: "dotnet pack"
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    nobuild: true
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'nuget push'
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.nupkg;!$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/**/*.symbols.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: '<Name of Your Feed>'
    versioningScheme: 'off'
    allowPackageConflicts: true
```

https://medium.com/@gstvribs/how-to-use-and-deploy-azure-devops-artifacts-on-azure-pipelines-with-dotnet-dockerized-8cebd724f752

Comment: Thanks, you have no idea how many articles I have read. This really helped me

Answer (score 0):

Please add to `dotnet pack` for instance setting like this to your inputs:

```
packDirectory: "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/packages"
```

And then to `dotnet push` setting like this:

```
packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/packages/*.*nupkg'
```

In your approach it simply try to find packages in defualt folder but you didn't put packages there.

Comment: hi, thats not working :/ it still says the package with this pattern was not found at nuget push